# when to use Dispatcher in mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Following Jason Dolinger video I've crated DispatchingWcfModel that decorates normal model. But I don't understand why do I need it. Should I always use some kind of Dispatching model? What if I will use normal model instead of dispatching model? Why do I need "Dispatcher"?

```
class DispatchingWcfModel : IWcfModel
{

    private readonly IWcfModel _underlying;
    private readonly Dispatcher _currentDispatcher;

    public DispatchingWcfModel(IWcfModel model)
    {
        _currentDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        _underlying = model;
        _underlying.DataArrived += _underlying_DataArrived;
    }

    private void _underlying_DataArrived(List<ConsoleData> obj)
    {
        Action dispatchAction = () =>
        {
            if (DataArrived != null)
            {
                DataArrived(obj);
            }
        };
        _currentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, dispatchAction);
    }

    public List<ConsoleData> DataList
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public event Action<List<ConsoleData>> DataArrived;
}
```

Comment: I think you'd better add a link to Jason's video. I assume most people didn't see it and might not take into account the reasons he had to implement such a ViewModel. Right now for me (I haven't seen the video) I think this ViewModel is pointless.

Comment: this video is not available for a while for some reason, located here http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `DispatchingWcfModel` class wrap up injected `IWcfModel` and guarantee that when a new data comes - changes would be dispatched to UI in safe way event `IWcfModel.DataArrived` event has been raised in background thread, so `DispatchingWcfModel` always pushes callback using Dispatcher to the UI Thread.

**More detailed:** In your example `DispatchingWcfModel` class subscribing to an event of injected `IWcfModel`, so when event has been raised - event handler `_underlying_DataArrived` would be called and what **most important point** - it would be called on the thread which actually raising an event so it is possible that calling thread would not be a UI Thread so any changes to UI controls would be failed, to avoid this Dispatched is used.

In WPF Dispatcher is useful when you need to update UI elements so this should be done in UI Thread. Right way to do this - delegate this work to Dispatcher which persitsting a queue of workitems (requests) which should be performed on the UIThread.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx):

> In WPF, a DispatcherObject can only be accessed by the Dispatcher it
>   is associated with.  For example, a background thread cannot update
>   the contents of a Button that is associated with the Dispatcher on the
>   UI thread. In order for the background thread to access the Content
>   property of the Button, the background thread must delegate the work
>   to the Dispatcher associated with the UI thread. This is accomplished
>   by using either Invoke or BeginInvoke. Invoke is synchronous and
>   BeginInvoke is asynchronous. The operation is added to the queue of
>   the Dispatcher at the specified DispatcherPriority.

Comment: still not clear.. what if someone will add some action to `DataArrived` that is not UI-specific. then UI thread will be used for not-UI work. Also it is not clear how to determine if I'm updating UI... I think that if I update ViewModel - this means that i'm updating UI, because UI listen for changes in ViewModel. Also I don't understand why this guy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx doesn't use `Dispatcher`. Using `Dispatcher` is not mandatory?

Comment: From MVVM perspectives for me is not clear at all why Model (DispatchingWcfModel) is aware of such stuff like pushing changes to UI thread, this should be done by ViewModel. And this is not a problem executing some code block in UI thread since by default all application/s code executing in the main thread which is UI Thread

Comment: model just notifies any interested parties that new data is arrived and nothing else. only model knows when it's data is updated...

Answer (score 1):

The `Dispatcher` is WPF's internal message queue for the main UI thread. It can be used from a Background thread to run commands on the main UI thread of an application.

This is important because WPF doesn't let you access objects which were created on other threads. For example, if a Button is created on the main UI thread, then you cannot modify this button from another thread, but you can use the Dispatcher from another thread to send a command to the main UI thread to update the button.

This applies to all objects, not just UI Elements. If something like an `ObservableCollection` is created on one thread, another thread cannot modify it. Because of this, all objects are usually created on the main UI thread.

Dispatcher messages can get processed synchronously or asynchronously. For example,

```
// Will execute SomeMethod on the main UI thread synchronously
Dispatcher.Invoke(SomeMethod);

// Will execute SomeMethod on the main UI thread asynchronously
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(SomeMethod);
```

The Dispatcher also has different queues for different priorities of messages, and you can specify a [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) with your message to make something run at a specified time.

```
// Will execute SomeMethod on the main UI thread synchronously, 
// at the same priority as Rendering controls
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, SomeMethod);

// Will execute SomeMethod on the main UI thread asynchronously, 
// at the same priority as background processes
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, SomeMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

The dispatcher is used to access graphical user elements. These user elements are created in the behalve of the dispatcher. Other threads are not allowed to access them. So when you want to access gui elements you have to invoke the operation on the dispatcher.

But a dispatching model seems to be the wrong approach. These things should be done in the view model. That's on of the the reasons why there is a view model. The model is usually a POCO or a DTO, so you cannot rely on every model implementing your IWcfModel interface.

I don't know the video you are talking about, but it seems that the authors understanding of MVVM is a little bit off the mark.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into much technical detail (upvote the other answers here), you use the Dispatcher when

1. you wish to do something later
2. you wish to do something on the UI thread

No. 2 is the obvious choice when multithreading.  Updates to the UI have to be moved, or "marshalled", to the UI thread when called from a background thread.  If you don't know what this means, do a little reading here, as this is one of the largest hurdles a user new to multithreaded development has to learn and there are thousands of related questions to be found here.

No. 1 is a little more obscure, but is possible thanks to overloads of `BeginInvoke` that take  a [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) value.

There can be times when you are doing work in the UI thread, and you *know* you want to update the UI, but you need to do it *later*.  Examples include updates that may need to wait until the user has completed typing, lest the next key pressed wipes out your UI changes.